# Showing information based on an entries category

Tags: conditionals, categories

I'm trying to display some information based on the category an entry is in, however I can't get my head around it… If the entry is in more than 1 category it'll still show the information, how do I make it work so if category_id is selected at all it'll not show the information? Here's my current code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="courses" category="2"}
  {categories show_group="2"}
    {if category_id != "2"}
       {course_start-date format='%d %M %Y'}
    {/if}
 {/categories}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. php (PHP Parsing Stage: ouput)

   {exp:channel:entries channel="courses" category="2"}

   ```
   <?php $excludefrom = '|{categories}{category_id}|{/categories}'; ?> 
   <?php if (substr_count($excludefrom, "|2|") == 0){?> 
         {course_start-date format='%d %M %Y'}
   <?php } ?>
   ```

   {/exp:channel:entries}

   (you can do the same using [Switchee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee) the same way with regex)

*update*

Additional solution:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="courses" category="2"}

   {if "{categories show_group="2"}2{/categories}" != "2"}
      {course_start-date format='%d %M %Y'}
   {/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Thanks Max, explains why I haven't been able to get it to work. Is there definetly no way I can achieve this by using ExpressionEngine's tags alone?

Comment: I just updated my post - possible second solution will be good for you.